# VB - Get Visual Studios 2010 to stop recommending VB6 code

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

This is something that annoys me to no end, whenever I have to convert something to a value (for example,lets say I have to convert something to a boolean) visual studios will give you their advice of CBool, which works, but that's VB6 and I do not want that.

I tried looking everywhere, but no luck, does anyone know how I can get Visual Studio to stop suggesting VB 6 solutions and instead suggest .NET solutions (like use convert.ToBoolean)?

If you know of a plugin that does it, I'm open to that as well.

Thank Guys.

Comment: CBool was part of VB6, but it is part of VB.NET as well. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s2dy91zy(v=vs.80).aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `CBool()` operator and it's companions (even CType) are **not** VB6.  They are **operators** rather than functions, and still very much a part of modern VB.Net.  The have syntax that resembles code from the old vb6 style, which is unfortunate, but aside from that there is nothing wrong from them.

The alternative of `Convert.ToBoolean()`, on the other hand, is a function.  The difference is that `Convert.ToBoolean()` can *convert* a much larger range of values, at the cost of drastically reduced performance, while `CBool` can only *cast* something that already is (or very nearly already is) a boolean and maybe just doesn't have the exact type match that you need.

The trick here is contrasting casting operators like CBool() with VB6-era functions, like Len(), Trim(), DateAdd(), Ubound(), etc.  The latter should definitely be avoided in favor of a more modern style.

Comment: You can also ctype(YourVariable,boolean) or even directCast if you want to squeeze every bit of performance out of it.

Comment: +1 VB.Net docs on CBool [say](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s2dy91zy.aspx) "as a rule, you should use the Visual Basic type conversion functions in preference to the .NET Framework methods". One question though, is `CBool` really a cast? `CBool("true")` returns `True` - isn't that a conversion rather than a cast?

Comment: @MarkJ The rules for casting in VB are different than the rules for even, say C#. And even C# allows you do to some conversions via casts... between the various types of ints and floats, for example.